# Running node from a bash script: output console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I'm running a node script from bash. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing mynodescript.js..."
node mynodescript.js
```

Inside "mynodescript.js" I have a console.log("Hello from mynodescript.js"). How can I do to output it on my terminal window? So executing the bash script above would output something like:

```
> Executing mynodescript.js...
> Hello from mynodescript.js
```

Comment: It doesn't do this by default?

Comment: This is the default, unless something's changed. Maybe stdout is closed and reopened into a file? Maybe a logging library does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code in your node script should work:
    console.log('some text');

If it doesn't, make sure your PATH is correct within the shell script when executing node.  The path to your node binary isn't set at the system level (within /etc/paths) then you may need to use the /absolute/path/to/node nodescript.js within the shell script.

If that isn't the issue, verify your node script syntax is correct.

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing mynodescript.js..."
node mynodescript.js 2>&1
```

Comment: I didn't get to test this. It was working just the way I had it, I just had to restart my terminal. Thanks anyway.